# inconsistent DirectoryIterator+FilterIterator behaviour in PHP?

Tags: php, spl

I wrote a script that is using the FilterIterator class that comes from the Standard PHP Library (SPL) and I get different behabours accross PHP 5.x versions :( Here the accept() function:

```
public function accept()
{   
$current = $this->current();
print_r($current);      

    return true;
}
```

and heres its output for PHP 5.3.1:

```
DirectoryIterator Object
(
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /Users/alex/Sites/dev/php/fscms/content/.
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => .
    [glob:DirectoryIterator:private] => 
    [subPathName:RecursiveDirectoryIterator:private] => 
)
DirectoryIterator Object
(
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /Users/alex/Sites/dev/php/fscms/content/..
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => ..
    [glob:DirectoryIterator:private] => 
    [subPathName:RecursiveDirectoryIterator:private] => 
)
DirectoryIterator Object
(
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /Users/alex/Sites/dev/php/fscms/content/.DS_Store
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => .DS_Store
    [glob:DirectoryIterator:private] => 
    [subPathName:RecursiveDirectoryIterator:private] => 
)
```

and heres what I get with the same code under PHP 5.2.5

```
DirectoryIterator Object
(
)
DirectoryIterator Object
(
)
DirectoryIterator Object
(
)
```

The latter has permission 755 on all files. Whats up with dat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is actually OK! Calling methods on the seemingly empty DirectoryIterator objects works. The issues I was having were elsewhere and had to do with cloning these objects. Seems PHP 5.3 clones deep while 5.2 don't so all the references get killed on each iteration (or something like that). Its an ugly, un-documented mess: PHP sucks!

Answer (score 0):

From PHP.net:

- Note: As of PHP 5.3.0 this extension can no longer be disabled and is therefore always available.

Possibly your PHP 5.2.5 configuration is in some way incomplete/wrong? Do you have your error log leve set to display warnings? If not, adjust it and run your code again to see if its throwing any warnings ...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but the fact that the Class exists means that it __must__ be installed correctly, no? So I'm guessing there must be some sort of change in implementation between the versions.
Also, its on shared hosting so I don't have control over it. I was hoping to debug the script in an "average" server to make it more robust.

Comment: aslo, i have 
    php_flag display_errors on
on my .htaccess file. no errors coming up :<

Comment: Yeah that's truly strange ... Maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: Yeah, its as if it sees the folder contents but doesn't instantiate the object property's for what it finds :-?